# Drupal Commons installation error

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-commons

I am trying to install drupal Commons from acquia, every time I try to install i get an error which says

```
Installing Commons

The installation has encountered an error.
Please continue to the error page
An error occurred. http://localhost/common/commons/install.php?locale=&profile=drupal_commons&id=1&op=do <br /> <b>Fatal error</b>: require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required './profiles/drupal_commons/modules/contrib/context/plugins/context_condition_context.inc' (include_path='.;C:\Documents and Settings\jkancher\My Documents\Downloads\xampp\php\pear\') in <b>C:\Documents and Settings\jkancher\My Documents\Downloads\xampp\htdocs\common\commons\profiles\drupal_commons\modules\contrib\ctools\includes\plugins.inc</b> on line <b>747</b><br />
```

I am using XAMPP on my home computer. I tried with different versions of PHP(5.2.9 and 5.3) but still no luck.

Please let me know if any of you ahd the same installation issue and was successful in installing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had problems the first time I tried to install Commons locally, changing the PHP memory limit solved it... Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you provide me an exact procedure of how to install commons, i'm pretty new to drupal and its a lot confusing to me.

Comment: As far as I remember the procedure is no different from a standard Drupal install. The only extra step I had to do was to increase the memory limit in PHP. For this , you simply need to find the php.ini file of the PHP version you're using and increase the "memory_limit" value to something like 96M.

Comment: yup now it works fine, I was increasing the max execution time till now, but it worked after i changed the memory limit. thanks for the hint..

Answer (score 0):

It means that the file PHP is trying to include (`./profiles/drupal_commons/modules/contrib/context/plugins/context_condition_context.inc`) isn't found, or the web server doesn't have sufficient permissions to read it.

Check in `/profiles/drupal_commons/modules/contrib/context/plugins/` to make sure that the `context_condition_context.inc` file exists and that the web server can read it (shouldn't really be an issue using XAMPP).

Some people have reported seeing some strange file extensions being added to the `context_condition_context.inc` file which causes Drupal not to find it. You can find one such report [here](http://drupal.org/node/1067704).

Hope that helps

Comment: The file does not exist. but it exists in a different location. shall i just copy the file to this location ?

Comment: I even tried copying the file to the other location, but it did not work out.

Comment: You could do but it might be better to grab fresh copy of commons and chuck the whole `profiles` folder back in just in case there's anything else missing. Try the single file first though just in case, you never know!

Comment: Is drupal commons installation similar to drupal ? or is there anything else that I need to do before starting the commons installation ?

Comment: Yep the core code is exactly the same, it's the `drupal_commons` profile that provides the extras to make it a Commons installation

Comment: I tried doing the whole thing again, but i still have the same issue, I wonder if I'm making a mistake and if there is any additional step that I'm missing from the normal drupal installation.

Comment: There's a [full guide here](http://commons.acquia.com/wiki/installing-drupal-commons), maybe that will help shed some light?

Comment: Thanks for that, but now I get a different error...

now it says

An error occurred. Please try reinstalling again.
Please continue to the error page
An error occurred. http://localhost/drup6/commons/install.php?locale=&profile=drupal_commons&id=2&op=do <br /> <b>Fatal error</b>: Call to a member function override_option() on a non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\drup6\commons\profiles\drupal_commons\modules\contrib\views\modules\comment.views_default.inc</b> on line <b>22</b><br />

Comment: is it due to a version of PHP that i'm using ??

Answer (score 0):

I also face same problem.
But it was solved by changing the php_execution_time to 120.
and then click on

> Please continue to the error page

it'll redirect to Configure to site.